# Primefaces rendered p:rowExpansion/p:column

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a p:datatable which updates based on a p:commandButton, shown below:

```
<p:commandButton id="diff" value="Run" 
      actionListener="#{difference.diffButtonListener}" 
      update="differenceContent infoPanel modificationTable" />

<p:dataTable id="modificationTable" value="#{difference.results}" var="code" 
            paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,25,50" rows="5" style="width:100%"
            resizableColumns="true" draggableColumns="true"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            rowKey="#{result.hashCode()}"
            rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

            <p:column styleClass="row-toggle" rendered="#{difference.toggleRowRendered}">
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>

            <c:forEach items="#{difference.columns}" var="col">
                <ui:param name="rowValue" value="#{difference.getObjectValue(code, col)}" />
                <p:column headerText="#{col.label}" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowValue}" styleClass="#{difference.getColStyleClass(rowIndex, code, col)}" />
                </p:column>
            </c:forEach>

            <p:rowExpansion rendered="#{difference.rowExpansionRendered}">
                <p:dataTable id="expandedTable" value="#{code.value}" var="modCode"
                    paginator="false" rows="10" rowKey="#{expandedResult.hashCode()}">

                    <!-- empty column for row toggler -->
                    <p:column style="width:16px"/>
                    <c:forEach  items="#{difference.columns}" var="col">
                        <ui:param name="subRowValue" value="#{difference.getObjectValue(modCode, col)}" />
                        <p:column headerText="#{col.label}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subRowValue}" styleClass="#{difference.getColStyleClass(rowIndex, modCode, col)}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </c:forEach>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:rowExpansion>

        </p:dataTable>
```

For this view I have data in 4 forms: Added, Deleted, Modified, and All which is an aggregate A/D/M view.  The way this should work is that in Added and Deleted views only a simple dataTable is displayed, no row expansion or rowToggler.  In Modified and All views, the rowToggler and expansion should be available to display modified content in two rows (original vs. modified).  This "appears" to be working very nicely, with the only caveat being order of operation.

If I view the All or Modified content first, no problem, however once I view the Added or Deleted content the rowToggler and rowExpansion are removed (as they should be), but are gone forever.  Based on my understanding of rendering (through components already in the DOM) this should work w/o flaw...  I've also placed logging information into toggleRowRendered and rowExpansionRendered methods (in addition to actually debugging) to verify my outcome when switching back to All or Modified.

`DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-94] - Toggle column rendering: true`
`19:38:53,222 DEBUG [Difference:352:isRowExpansionRendered]`

`DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-94] - Toggle row expansion rendering: true`
`19:38:53,223 DEBUG [Difference:347:isToggleRowRendered]`

Also, differenceContent in the p:commandButton update is a parent panel to the dataTable.  It should facilitate rendering as well.